# Find All Records with the same Id in SQL Table that are missing a specific record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hey guys I'm debugging an issue where a specific record doesn't have a value and I'm trying to go about finding all records where this issue happens.

In my table there is a record for each Event for the same OrderId and ProductId. There should be a Event called `ShipConfirm` and I want to find every ProductId or OrderId within my table that is missing that Event.

The table looks like this:

| OrderId | ProductId | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9845 | Checkout |
| 1 | 9845 | CheckInventory |
| 1 | 9845 | SupplierAssignment |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Select distinct OrderId, ProductId from Table T
where Event != 'ShipConfirm'
and concat(OrderId,ProductId) not in (Select distinct concat(OrderId,ProductId) 
from table where OrderId = t.OrderId 
and ProductId = T.ProductId and Event = 'ShipConfirm');
```

Answer (score -1):

Aggregation provides one simple option:

```sql
SELECT OrderId, ProductId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY OrderId, ProductId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Event = 'ShipConfirm' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Query error: No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: BOOL. Supported signatures: SUM(INT64); SUM(FLOAT64); SUM(NUMERIC); SUM(BIGNUMERIC); SUM(INTERVAL)`

Comment: @Deivinho Try the updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

A slightly different answer:

```
with 
input as (
select 1 as OrderId, 9845 as ProductId, 'Checkout' as Event union all
select 1, 9845, 'CheckInventory' union all
select 1, 9845, 'SupplierAssignment'
)

select OrderId, ProductId
from input
group by OrderId, ProductId
having countif(Event = 'ShipConfirm') = 0
```